# Splitting a large multi-thread binary into smaller individual processes/binaries

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I'm not sure if the title accurately describes what I want to do but here's the rub:

We have a large and hairy codebase (not-invented-here courtesy of Elbonian Code Slaves) which currently compiles as one big binary which internally creates several pthreads for various specific tasks, communicating through IPC messages.

It's not ideal for a number of reasons, and several of the threads would be better as independent autonomous processes as they are all individual specific "workers" rather than multiple instances of the same piece of code.

I feel a bit like I'm missing some trick, is our only option to split off the various thread code and compile each as a standalone executable invoked using `system()` or `exec()` from the main blob of code? It feels clunky somehow.

Comment: If they communicate (using IPC or whatever) they are *not* independent.

Comment: "Missing a trick" in terms of a quick and easy way to automagically convert the threads to processes?

Comment: @joop - independent as in each doing a different task, for example one is acting as a comms bridge for the rest, one is handling alarm states, one is running scheduled events... @joe - not in a "please do my homework for me" way, just that it always feels clunky to replace several calls to `pthread_create(func_n)` with `system("new_proc_1")`, `system("new_proc_n")` etc.

Comment: `system()` won't help you much, since it waits for the completion of the spawned process. `fork()` may be fragile in a multithreaded program. Your best bet is `posix_spawn()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take a part of your program that currently runs as a thread, and instead run it as a separate process launched by your main program, then you have two main options:

1. Instead of calling `pthread_create()`, `fork()` and in the child process call the thread-start function directly (do not use any of the exec-family functions).
2. Compile the code that the the thread executes as a separate executable.  Launch that executable at need by the standard `fork / exec` sequence.  (Or you could use `system()` instead of fork/exec, but don't.  Doing so needlessly brings the shell into it, and also gives you much less control.)

The former has the disadvantage that each process image contains a lot of code that it will never use, since each is a complete copy of everything.  Inasmuch as under Linux `fork()` uses copy-on-write, however, that's mostly an address-space issue, not a resource-wastage issue.

The latter has the disadvantage that the main program needs to be able to find the child programs on the file system.  That's not necessarily a *hard* problem, mind you, but it is substantially different from already having the needed code at hand.  If there is any way that any of the child programs would be independently useful, however, then breaking them out as separate programs makes a fair amount of sense.

Do note, by the way, that I do not in general accept your premise that it is inappropriate to implement specific for-purpose workers as threads.  If you want to break out such tasks, however, then the above are your available alternatives.

**Edited to add:**

As @EOF pointed out, if you intend that after the revamp your main process will still be multi-threaded (that is, if you intend to convert only some threads to child processes) then you need to be aware of a significant restriction placed by POSIX:

> If a multi-threaded process calls fork(), [...] to avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called.

On the other hand, I'm pretty sure the relevant definition of "multi-threaded" is that the process has multiple live threads *at the time `fork()` is called*.  It should not present a problem if the child processes are all forked off before any additional threads are created, or after all but one thread is joined.

Comment: In a multithreaded process, `fork()` is pretty tough to use safely. As best as I understand, you can't call any non-async-safe functions in the child, which may be a rather severe restriction.

Comment: John - Without lengthy descriptions of the system it's hard to explain my reasoning but the bits I want to split off are very much more like standalone processes / daemons serving multiple other processes (and threads thereof), and the original big "blob" has to be completely killed & restarted for various reasons where it would be desirable for some of the threads to stay running. At least, until we eventually exorcise all the Elbonian code sometime around 2025...

Comment: @EOF, yes, POSIX permits the child process resulting from the `fork()` of a multi-threaded program to call only async-signal-safe functions until such time as it successfully calls one of the exec-family functions.  This is indeed a significant restriction, and I should have mentioned it.  However, it only applies to the present case if the process will continue to *be* a multithreaded process after the postulated overhaul.

Comment: Updated the answer with some commentary about forking in multithreaded programs.